# Two dimensional array java - Multiple errors

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am trying to create a two dimensional array put it keeps giving me errors.~
Could you help figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
char [][] numero0 = new char [7][4];
numero0[][] = { {'.', '#', '#', '.'},
                {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                {'.', '.', '.', '.'},
                {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                {'.', '#', '#', '.'} };
```

Erros:

illegal start of expression
not a statement
';' expected

Comment: In the second line, you use the array initialization syntax, that is only valid when declaring an array. But you assigning to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use initializer syntax, except when declaring the array variable.

So, either:

```
char[][] array = { { ... } };
```

or

```
char[][] array = new char[][] { { ... } };
```

or

```
char[][] array;  // Don't assign new char[7][4] here, it is overwritten in the next line.
array = new char[][] { { ... } };
```

Comment: Sorry, but that did no solve the errors. The same error messages keep popping up.

Comment: [It works just fine](https://ideone.com/lbULjp).

Answer (score 0):

`numero0[][] = { { ... }};` should be `numero0 = new char[][] { { ... } };`.

Please see [the following snippet](https://ideone.com/E8Z9eb).

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code :**

```
public class TwoDarray {
    public static void main(String args[]){


        char numero0[][] = { {'.', '#', '#', '.'},
                        {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                        {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                        {'.', '.', '.', '.'},
                        {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                        {'#', '.', '.', '#'},
                        {'.', '#', '#', '.'} };


        for (int i = 0; i < numero0.length; i++) { //printing 2d-array as matrix with index so that you get a better picture of 2d array.
            for (int j = 0; j < numero0[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ( " + i + "," + j + " ) " + numero0[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


}
```

> printing 2d-array as matrix with index so that you get a better
>   picture of 2d array.

**Output :**

[image]

**Correct way To declare and Initialize two dimensional Array in Java :**

**Syntax to Declare Multidimensional Array in java :**

```
dataType[][] arrayRefVar; (or)  
dataType [][]arrayRefVar; (or)  
dataType arrayRefVar[][]; (or)  
dataType []arrayRefVar[];
```

**Example to instantiate Multidimensional Array in java :**

```
int[][] arr=new int[3][3];//3 row and 3 column
```

**Example to initialize Multidimensional Array in java :**

```
arr[0][0]=1;  
arr[0][1]=2;  
arr[0][2]=3;  
arr[1][0]=4;  
arr[1][1]=5;  
arr[1][2]=6;  
arr[2][0]=7;  
arr[2][1]=8;  
arr[2][2]=9;
```

**Declaring and initializing 2D array :**

```
int arr[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

**NOTE:**

> You were Instantiating on line 1 i.e **char [][] numero0 = new char
>   [7][4];** and Trying to initialize array without providing index on
>   second line.
>
> You can use loop to initialize and print multidimensional array.

I hope I was helpful :)